# Verify exact json in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

REST Services Testing with JMeter: I have exact JSON that is my expected result, please help me to define this assertion in JMeter. For example, my expected response from a GET request is exactly:

```
[ {
  "id" : "FR",
  "description" : "France",
  "defaultLanguageId" : "fr",
  "defaultTimezone" : "Europe/Paris"
}, {
  "id" : "IT",
  "description" : "Italy",
  "defaultLanguageId" : "it",
  "defaultTimezone" : "Europe/Rome"
} ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and Groovy language like:

1. Add JSR223 Assertion as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into the JSR223 Assertion "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

   JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper();

   def expected = slurper.parseText("[\n" +
                   "  {\n" +
                   "    \"id\": \"FR\",\n" +
                   "    \"description\": \"France\",\n" +
                   "    \"defaultLanguageId\": \"fr\",\n" +
                   "    \"defaultTimezone\": \"Europe/Paris\"\n" +
                   "  },\n" +
                   "  {\n" +
                   "    \"id\": \"IT\",\n" +
                   "    \"description\": \"Italy\",\n" +
                   "    \"defaultLanguageId\": \"it\",\n" +
                   "    \"defaultTimezone\": \"Europe/Rome\"\n" +
                   "  }\n" +
                   "]");
   def actual = slurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());

   if (expected != actual) {
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
   }
   ```

Using this approach you will be able to compare JSON structures and it won't fail in case of different nodes order or extra space or whatever. If you need to check order and markup as well - just use normal [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) in `Equals` mode like:

[image: Response Assertion]

References:

- [Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

Comment: I would prefer to use response assertion, but it doesn't seem to work. Is it defined correctly:

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you can help me to define it as Response Assertion, I tried the definition as shown on the screeshot: http://s61.photobucket.com/user/AJ6FZ3h/library/ but it is not working this way. What is wrong?

Comment: I updated the answer with the screenshot, however I repeat, this approach will be **very** fragile, any extra space, any new line, any change in order of JSON nodes will cause failure, my recommendation is going for Groovy approach

Comment: Thank you so very much.  With Response Assertion equal it returns fail - regardless that the json is the same, probably  as you said there is some space or other small difference. What would you advise me to use if I have to verify a json with tenths and even hundred nodes? Is there a converter of the json to this code readable json format?

Comment: You might want to try [JSON Formatter PostProcessor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONFormatter/), but I strongly advice you **third** time to go for JSR223 Assertion and Groovy language approach. It is not that complex, check out [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) for entry level information and scripting best practices

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I'm trying the approach with your script, but I'm getting an error message for the language: Assertion error: true
Assertion failure: false
Assertion failure message: javax.script.ScriptException: Cannot find engine named: 'Groovy', ensure you set language field in JSR223 Test Element:JSR223 Assertion

Comment: You either need to upgrade to [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) which includes Groovy or install Groovy jar separately (just download [groovy-all.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all), drop it to JMeter's "lib" folder and restart JMeter)

Comment: I'm so thankful. It worked perfectly and I found that with NetBeans and Java Text Copy Paste Module I can successfully covert the jsons. Million thanks